# Clean text data in Python

Tags: python, text, nlp, data-cleaning

I want to create a new column for the text data (every row for that column is one description) after removing all numbers (such as 189, 98001), special characters ( ‘  ,  _, “, (, ) ), and letters with numbers or special characters (e21x16, e267, e4, e88889, entry778, id2, n27th, pv3,  ).

So I wrote the function below. However, the returned results still contain numbers, and special characters. Basically, my goal is to keep only English words, and abbreviations. Does anyone know why my function is not working.

```
def standardize_text(df, text_field):
  df[text_field] = df[text_field].str.lower()
  df[text_field] = df[text_field].str.replace(r'(', '') 
  df[text_field] = df[text_field].str.replace(r')', '')
  df[text_field] = df[text_field].str.replace(r',', '')
  df[text_field] = df[text_field].str.replace(r'_', '')
  df[text_field] = df[text_field].str.replace(r"'", "")
  df[text_field] = df[text_field].str.replace(r"^[a-z]+\[0-9]+$", "")
  df[text_field] = df[text_field].str.replace(r"^[0-9]{1,2,3,4,5}$", "")
  return df
```

Comment: Why do yo have a `'\'` in `r"^[a-z]+\[0-9]+$"`?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how the column is and what you would like it to be?

Comment: You also should provide the type of `df` and its members.

Comment: Here is one example: "(n)fully sprinklered 42' x 57', three story three unit apartment(townh"(there are also some typos which I am not sure how to handle). As I want to do topic modeling on these descriptions, so I will need to remove non-words such as numbers and special characters. I am not sure if this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Use a library named 'textcleaner'. See [repository](https://github.com/YugantM/textcleaner) and [link](https://pypi.org/project/textcleaner/). 
This [article](https://medium.com/@yuganthadiyal/textcleaner-a-data-pre-processing-library-1a234eec02dd) might help you.

```
!pip install textcleaner
import textcleaner as tc
```

or

```
from textcleaner import *
```

now just call `main_cleaner(<FILE_NAME>)`
it will return you list of words with all the basic pre-processing.

Answer (score -1):

You either have to set the `inplace` parameter of the `replace` function to true or assign the returned df to the `df` variable

Comment: Surely the OP does assign the results to the same field.

Comment: sorry. the numbers didn't get replaced because your regex `"^[a-z]+\[0-9]+$"` requires the strings to end in a digit. try `"^[a-z]+\[0-9]+"` or `"\d+"`